# IPTC data does not parsing correctly for specific images

Tags: php

I am using iptcparse to fetch the IPTC data from images(jpg's) and it is also working for most of images but in some JPEGs it shows **Incorrect APP1 Exif Identifier** error code.

Here is the sample code:

```
 $size = getimagesize('apple.jpg', $info);
 if(isset($info['APP13']))
 {
     $iptc = iptcparse($info['APP13']);
     echo '<pre>';
     print_r($iptc);
 }
```

I have checked metadata with Photoshop and metadata shows correctly. Can anyone share their thoughts?

Comment: Adobe products, including Photoshop, in addition to IPTC store metadata in XMP. So, you probably saw metadata from XMP.